# Why is my string not convertible to datetime?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, c#-4.0, ado.net

I am passing 2 dates to a stored procedure but conversion throws an error

> String not convertible to datetime

Code:

```
 txtFromDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
 txtToDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

 System.Data.DataTable dt = RejFiles.RejectedFiles(Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text.Trim()), Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text.Trim()), user.OfficeID, user.Type_ID);
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RejectedFiles] 
     (@FromDate SMALLDATETIME,  
      @ToDate SMALLDATETIME,  
      @OfficeID INT = 0,  
      @Type INT = 0)
```

and the database stores the dates in particular table like this:

```
2014-03-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: why not pass them as datetime ?

Comment: You cannot perform conversion in isolation. Hint: what is "8/7/2016 05:12", Aug-7 or July-8?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad woh to krliye bhai, ab bhi kaam nahi kr raha

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: then ? what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

This is just messed up.  Why are you formatting dates that are not the same as you local culture?

```
DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))
```

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: that's not even an excuse, there must be a way around